# Why browser can't find the js-files from the `../lib/` (relative) location?

Tags: javascript

I learn WebGL. I read [this book](https://sites.google.com/site/webglbook/) and try to run [its samples](https://sites.google.com/site/webglbook/home/downloads). I set the current directory for the `D:\WebGL\ch02` and run the local web-server:

```
python -m http.server 8001
```

and open the `http://localhost:8001/ColoredPoints.html` file. But I get an error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getWebGLContext is not defined

From the `D:/WebGL/ch02/ColoredPoints.html` file:

```
<script src="../lib/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/webgl-debug.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/cuon-utils.js"></script>
<script src="ColoredPoints.js"></script>
```

If I copy the `../lib/` directory (with its js-files) into *current subdirectory* - all works fine. The `../lib/` is the common directory (with the common js-files) for the all samples of the book.

Why it doesn't work for the `../lib/` location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the website is `D:\WebGL\ch02`

You cannot go above it.

If you want to serve files from `D:\WebGL\lib` then you need to either set the root of the site to `D:\WebGL\` or move the `lib` directory inside `ch02` (and remove the `..`).

Answer (score 2):

.. goes up one level, but you are already at the root of your hostname. So you will have to put them into a sub-directory and use . instead of ..