# html file not displaying in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, mozilla

I'm new to webGL and web development in general. Whenever I try to run my .html code in Firefox I get a blank page and the error:
"ReferenceError: getWebGLContext is not defined" 
I've read through this question: [Why browser can't find the js-files from the `../lib/` (relative) location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560943/why-browser-cant-find-the-js-files-from-the-lib-relative-location) and I'm using the same webGL libraries/utilities and have all three downloaded onto my computer. Currently my .html file opens in Firefox as file:/// when it should be running as in http://. When I compare my issues to the issues in the link I see they are using a local host. Would this fix my problem and how do I connect to the local host? 
These are the libraries:

```
<script src="../lib/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/webgl-debug.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/cuon-utils.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why browser can't find the js-files from the \`../lib/\` (relative) location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28560943/why-browser-cant-find-the-js-files-from-the-lib-relative-location)

Comment: Yes it would, please [read this MDN article on setting up a basic working environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Set_up_a_basic_working_environment), while you're at it read the prerequisites mentioned at the top of the article.

Comment: Ugh, telling people to setup apache, nginx, iis etc. That's really overkill and extremely inflexible. There's some terse [instructions here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/webgl/2605/getting-started-with-webgl/8648/installation-or-setup) for much simpler web servers.